# Task scheduler error:No such file or directory

Tags: windows, batch, scheduled-tasks

I had a python script which involves opening an absolute path and I used double backslash in the file name, and it works perfectly fine, and the batch file of it works too. But when i use windows tsak scheduler to run it, it shows

No such file or directory:H:\\gary\\file\\test.pdf

I tried to use forward slash to replace backward slash, this works perfectly fine in batch file too, but same error occurs when i run it in task scheduler:

No such file or directory: H:/gary/file/test.pdf

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does your H: drive is network one mapped to a letter? If so use UNC path to file (\\\\server\\share\\folder\\filename.ext) instead of mapped drive.

Comment: @Akina thanks for your answer, it is a network drive and it works after using UNC path as you suggested

Comment: If you want to use mapped drives in scheduled tasks (with highest privileges), enable the `EnableLinkedConnections` registry value. [Mapped drives not seen from elevated Command Prompt and Task Scheduler](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/mapped-drives-not-seen-elevated-command-prompt-task-scheduler/)